# Setting up on Macbook Pro M1 Tenserflow with OpenCV, Scipy, Scikit-learn

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, scikit-learn, scipy, apple-m1

I think I read pretty much most of the guides on setting up tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, object detection on Mac M1 on BigSur v11.6. I managed to figure out most of the errors after more than 2 weeks. But I am stuck at OpenCV setup. I tried to compile it from source but seems like it can't find the modules from its core package so constantly can't make the file after the successful cmake build. It fails at different stages, crying for different libraries, despite they are there but max reached 31% after multiple cmake and deletion of the build folder or the cmake cash file. So I am not sure what to do in order to make successfully the file.
I git cloned and unzipped the **opencv-4.5.0** and **opencv_contrib-4.5.0** in my miniforge3 directory. Then I created a folder "**build**" in my opencv-4.5.0 folder and the cmake command I use in it is (my miniforge conda environment is called silicon and made sure I am using arch arm64 in bash environment):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64 -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 -DWITH_OPENJPEG=OFF -DWITH_IPP=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/adi/miniforge3/opencv_contrib-4.5.0/modules -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/Users/adi/miniforge3/envs/silicon/bin/python3.8 -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON /Users/adi/miniforge3/opencv-4.5.0
```

So it cries like:

```
[ 20%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.dylib
[ 20%] Built target opencv_core
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

or also like in another tries was initially asking for **calib3d** or **dnn** but those libraries are there in the main folder opencv-4.5.0.

**The other way I try to install openCV is with conda:**

```
conda install opencv
```

But then when I test with

```
python -c "import cv2; cv2.__version__"
```

it seems like it searches for the **ffmepg** via homebrew (I didn't install any of these via homebrew but with conda). So it complained:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/adi/miniforge3/envs/silicon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/adi/miniforge3/envs/silicon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/adi/miniforge3/envs/silicon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Though I have these libs, so when I searched with: find /usr/ -name 'libavcodec.58.dylib' I could find many locations:

```
find: /usr//sbin/authserver: Permission denied
find: /usr//local/mysql-8.0.22-macos10.15-x86_64/keyring: Permission denied
find: /usr//local/mysql-8.0.22-macos10.15-x86_64/data: Permission denied
find: /usr//local/hw_mp_userdata/Internet_Manager/OnlineUpdate: Permission denied
/usr//local/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
/usr//local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
(silicon) MacBook-Pro:opencv-4.5.0 adi$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
ln: /opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib: No such file or directory
```

One of the guides said to install homebrew also in arm64 env, so I did it with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'  # create brew for intel (ibrew) and arm/ silicon
```

Not sure if that is affecting it but seems like it didn't do anything because still uses **/opt/homebrew/** instead of **/usr/local/**.
So any help would be highly appreciated if I can make any of the ways work. Ultimately I want to use Tenserflow Model Zoo Object Detection models. So all the other dependencies seems fine (for now) besides either OpenCV not working or if it is working with conda install then it seems that scipy and scikit-learn don't work.

Comment: Hi! Did you check this threads yet?                                                                                  https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/                     https://caffeinedev.medium.com/building-and-installing-opencv-on-m1-macbook-c4654b10c188                                                                
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6835OZT0Y5Y

Comment: Yes, sadly they did not help nor solve the problems :/

Comment: Ok. Attaching issue with similar stack trace and another possible solution for reference. Thanks!                                                              https://gist.github.com/capraMambrica/1984091     http://melvincabatuan.github.io/OpenCV-Install/

Comment: Hey @Adriyana. I am the author of the blog https://caffeinedev.medium.com/building-and-installing-opencv-on-m1-macbook-c4654b10c188 . the instructions are still working on system. I think you are missing something. If you are not able to I can help. Also, I was able install through conda also.

Comment: Hi @PrabhatKumarSahu, thank you I have seen your guide. I followed it many times but never worked fully and had issues :/ Not sure if Apple released some fix last days - need to check because I saw some changes in their metal page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also had lot of trouble trying to install both modules. I finally managed to do so but to be honest not really sure how and why. I leave below the requirements in case you might want to recreate the environment that worked in my case. You should have the conda Miniforge 3 installed :

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: osx-arm64
absl-py=1.0.0=pypi_0
astunparse=1.6.3=pypi_0
autocfg=0.0.8=pypi_0
blas=2.113=openblas
blas-devel=3.9.0=13_osxarm64_openblas
boto3=1.22.10=pypi_0
botocore=1.25.10=pypi_0
c-ares=1.18.1=h1a28f6b_0
ca-certificates=2022.2.1=hca03da5_0
cachetools=5.0.0=pypi_0
certifi=2021.10.8=py39hca03da5_2
charset-normalizer=2.0.12=pypi_0
cycler=0.11.0=pypi_0
expat=2.4.4=hc377ac9_0
flatbuffers=2.0=pypi_0
fonttools=4.31.1=pypi_0
gast=0.5.3=pypi_0
gluoncv=0.10.5=pypi_0
google-auth=2.6.0=pypi_0
google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.6=pypi_0
google-pasta=0.2.0=pypi_0
grpcio=1.42.0=py39h95c9599_0
h5py=3.6.0=py39h7fe8675_0
hdf5=1.12.1=h5aa262f_1
idna=3.3=pypi_0
importlib-metadata=4.11.3=pypi_0
jmespath=1.0.0=pypi_0
keras=2.8.0=pypi_0
keras-preprocessing=1.1.2=pypi_0
kiwisolver=1.4.0=pypi_0
krb5=1.19.2=h3b8d789_0
libblas=3.9.0=13_osxarm64_openblas
libcblas=3.9.0=13_osxarm64_openblas
libclang=13.0.0=pypi_0
libcurl=7.80.0=hc6d1d07_0
libcxx=12.0.0=hf6beb65_1
libedit=3.1.20210910=h1a28f6b_0
libev=4.33=h1a28f6b_1
libffi=3.4.2=hc377ac9_2
libgfortran=5.0.0=11_1_0_h6a59814_26
libgfortran5=11.1.0=h6a59814_26
libiconv=1.16=h1a28f6b_1
liblapack=3.9.0=13_osxarm64_openblas
liblapacke=3.9.0=13_osxarm64_openblas
libnghttp2=1.46.0=h95c9599_0
libopenblas=0.3.18=openmp_h5dd58f0_0
libssh2=1.9.0=hf27765b_1
llvm-openmp=12.0.0=haf9daa7_1
markdown=3.3.6=pypi_0
matplotlib=3.5.1=pypi_0
mxnet=1.6.0=pypi_0
ncurses=6.3=h1a28f6b_2
numpy=1.21.2=py39hb38b75b_0
numpy-base=1.21.2=py39h6269429_0
oauthlib=3.2.0=pypi_0
openblas=0.3.18=openmp_h3b88efd_0
opencv-python=4.5.5.64=pypi_0
openssl=1.1.1m=h1a28f6b_0
opt-einsum=3.3.0=pypi_0
packaging=21.3=pypi_0
pandas=1.4.1=pypi_0
pillow=9.0.1=pypi_0
pip=22.0.4=pypi_0
portalocker=2.4.0=pypi_0
protobuf=3.19.4=pypi_0
pyasn1=0.4.8=pypi_0
pyasn1-modules=0.2.8=pypi_0
pydot=1.4.2=pypi_0
pyparsing=3.0.7=pypi_0
python=3.9.7=hc70090a_1
python-dateutil=2.8.2=pypi_0
python-graphviz=0.8.4=pypi_0
pytz=2022.1=pypi_0
pyyaml=6.0=pypi_0
readline=8.1.2=h1a28f6b_1
requests=2.27.1=pypi_0
requests-oauthlib=1.3.1=pypi_0
rsa=4.8=pypi_0
s3transfer=0.5.2=pypi_0
scipy=1.8.0=pypi_0
setuptools=58.0.4=py39hca03da5_1
six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite=3.38.0=h1058600_0
tensorboard=2.8.0=pypi_0
tensorboard-data-server=0.6.1=pypi_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.1=pypi_0
tensorflow-deps=2.8.0=0
tensorflow-macos=2.8.0=pypi_0
termcolor=1.1.0=pypi_0
tf-estimator-nightly=2.8.0.dev2021122109=pypi_0
tk=8.6.11=hb8d0fd4_0
tqdm=4.63.1=pypi_0
typing-extensions=4.1.1=pypi_0
tzdata=2021e=hda174b7_0
urllib3=1.26.9=pypi_0
werkzeug=2.0.3=pypi_0
wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
wrapt=1.14.0=pypi_0
xz=5.2.5=h1a28f6b_0
yacs=0.1.8=pypi_0
zipp=3.7.0=pypi_0
zlib=1.2.11=h5a0b063_4
```

Comment: Note that this includes Tensorflow and Opencv (so not Scipy and Scikitlearn)